# Error when adding reaction roles in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to add a role on reactions and it seems to be working fine up to the point where I try to assign or remove a role, I'm getting an unspecified error and I don't know how to debug this

This is my code:

```
# Events
    @self._client.event
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
        if payload.user_id == self._client.user.id:
            return
        await self.on_reaction_add(payload.message_id, payload.user_id,
                                   payload.channel_id, payload.guild_id, payload.emoji)

    @self._client.event
    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
        if payload.user_id == self._client.user.id:
            return
        await self.on_reaction_remove(payload.message_id, payload.user_id,
                                      payload.channel_id, payload.guild_id, payload.emoji)
# Other methods
async def on_reaction_add(self, message_id: int, user_id: int, channel_id: int, server_id: int, emoji: str):
    await self.on_reaction(message_id, user_id, channel_id, server_id, emoji, True)

async def on_reaction_remove(self, message_id: int, user_id: int, channel_id: int, server_id: int, emoji: str):
    await self.on_reaction(message_id, user_id, channel_id, server_id, emoji, False)

async def on_reaction(self, message_id: int, user_id: int, channel_id: int, server_id: int, emoji: str, add: bool):
    result = self._database.find_reaction_role(str(server_id), str(channel_id), str(message_id), emoji)
    print(result)
    if result is not None:
        server = await self._client.fetch_guild(server_id)  # type: discord.Guild

        role = server.get_role(int(result.role_id))  # type: discord.Role

        user = server.get_member(user_id)
        if user is None:
            user = await server.fetch_member(user_id)  # type: discord.Member

        if user is not None and role is not None:
            if add:
                await user.add_roles(role, reason="reaction")
            else:
                await user.remove_roles(role, reason="reaction")
```

It fails on the last line with this error on console:

```
ERROR: root: on_raw_reaction_add
```

Comment: I don't think you should use on_raw_reaction_ and on_reaction_ at the same time, I recommend using raw for reaction roles since on_reaction_add works only on cached messages

Comment: on_reaction is an internal method called from on_raw_reaction_add and on_raw_reaction_remove

Comment: yes but on_reaction_ is also an event called when a reaction is added/removed, so the bug might be that it is called twice, once by your code in raw_reaction_, and once via the event
But i'm not sure

Comment: it's not defined as an event and it doesn't print twice, so I suppose that's not the issue here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error ocurred because `role = server.get_role(int(result.role_id))` was returning None, I fixed it by goingh through `server.fetch_roles`

```
@staticmethod
async def fetch_role(server: discord.Guild, role_id: int) -> discord.Role:
    roles = await server.fetch_roles()
    for role in roles:  # type: discord.Role
        if role.id == role_id:
            return role
```

The log issue was because I was overriding the logging function and forgot

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error occurees because you haven't got `on_reaction_add` and all the other functions inside the class and maybe missing the `self` parameter, that would be my guess